# Print More than one random number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and self taught. I would like to create a simple Dice rolling program but the problem I'm having is How to display more than one random integer I know I have to specify the dice roll as an integer but I'm not sure how Ill put part of the code below.
    # D&D Dice Roller

```
import random
import time

print("What dice would you like to roll")
sides = input()

if sides == 20:
    D20roll = random.randint(1,20)
    print ("How many dice would you like to roll")
    D20 = input()
    if D20 == 1:
    print(D20roll)
    if D20 == 2:
        print(D20roll + "," + D20roll)
    if D20 == 3:
        print(D20roll + "," + D20roll + "," +D20roll)
```

Comment: Read some basic tutorials on `for` and `while` loops. Those concepts allow you to repeatedly execute several lines of code.

Comment: Also, there's an indentation error at `print(D20roll)`. Indents are very important in Python.

Comment: Oh So, While D20 > x print(D20roll) x+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

sides = int (input ('Which die? ') )
count = int (input ('How many dice? ') )
print ( [random.randint (1, sides) for _ in range (count) ] )
```

Comment: Tanks heaps hopefully a few more months and I wont I'll be answering questions instead of asking. BTW Sorry for the ignorance i've only been learning for 2 days

Comment: No reason to be sorry. We are all learning something new each day.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing `D20roll = random.randint(1,20)` in a variable, call it multiple times to get random results:

Using `str.join`:

```
>>> D20 = 4
>>> print (", ".join(str(random.randint(1, 20)) for _ in range(D20)))
11, 4, 12, 4
```

Note that `input()` returns a string in python3.x, so you need to call `int()` on it:

```
sides = int(input())
D20 = int(input())
```